# Recommendations on Mac OSX (preferably Swift) video chat APIs?

Tags: macos, swift, video-streaming, webrtc, videochat

I'm tasked with developing a fullscreen native Mac OSX (Swift preferably, as I've been experimenting with it a lot lately) application that will connect two kiosks in two different parts of the US (each with high speed hardwired internet connections) in a video chat session. The kiosks must be able to automatically/programmatically connect and reconnect in case of lost connection. I was looking into TokBox but it seems their SDK/API is WebRTC, iOs, or Android oriented, otherwise it would have been a great choice at first glance. As I understand it, WebRTC is really just meant for browsers.

Does anyone have recommendations on an SDK/API that can help me accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure of why there was a downvote as I believe my question to be thorough and legitimate. Anyways, I think I may have answered my own question, but only in a theoretical/workaround sense. Perhaps I can use WebView in Mac OSX Swift and then use regular WebRTC via TokBox. Does anyone know if this will work?

Comment: Just a copy paste from the question topics: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC and make a web app out of the website. It will look and feel like a regular appp.    Take a look at Mike Kelly's [Refract](http://refract.mkelly.me/) for a painless web app packager.